# embedded jetty CrossDomainFilter not working

Tags: java, jetty, cors, embedded-jetty

I cannot find examples of embedded jetty with my combination of handlers and filters. For some reason I cannot identify I do not get CORS headers. Here is my current source:

```
private static Server setupJetty(Properties prop) {
    Server server = new Server(Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("port")));
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath(prop.getProperty("contextpath"));
    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler= setupLogging(server, prop.getProperty("logslocn"));
    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/*");
    jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

    // Tells the Jersey Servlet which REST service/class to load.
    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "org.example.pss.resources");
    context.addServlet(jerseyServlet, prop.getProperty("servletpath"));

    ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
    handler.addServletWithMapping(jerseyServlet, "/*");

    FilterHolder filterHolder = new FilterHolder(new CrossOriginFilter());
    filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "*");    // allowed origins comma separated
    filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_HEADERS_PARAM, "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Requested-With,Content-Length,Accept,Origin");
    filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.PREFLIGHT_MAX_AGE_PARAM, "5184000"); // 2 months
    filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOW_CREDENTIALS_PARAM, "true");
    filterHolder.setName("cross-origin");
    FilterMapping fm = new FilterMapping();
    fm.setFilterName("cross-origin");
    fm.setPathSpec("*");       
    handler.addFilter(filterHolder,fm);

    HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{context, handler, contexts, 
            new DefaultHandler(), requestLogHandler});
    server.setHandler(handlers);
    return server;
}
```

I also tried:

```
    FilterHolder filterHolder = new FilterHolder(new CrossOriginFilter());
    filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "/*");    // allowed origins comma separated
    filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_HEADERS_PARAM, "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Requested-With,Content-Length,Accept,Origin");
    filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.PREFLIGHT_MAX_AGE_PARAM, "5184000"); // 2 months
    filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOW_CREDENTIALS_PARAM, "true");
    context.addFilter(filterHolder,"/*",EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));

    HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{context, contexts, 
            new DefaultHandler(), requestLogHandler});
    server.setHandler(handlers);
```

With the same result, I never see the cross domain headers. What more do I need to do to get this filter to work?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `ServletHandler` directly, that's an internal class.
Filters are always part of the `ServletContextHandler` (or the more specialized `WebAppContext`)

Your configuration adds 2 servlets at the `/*` context path (that's a no-no)

Your configuration adds your `RequestLogHandler` after the `DefaultHandler` (which means the `RequestLogHandler` never runs)

`DefaultHandler` should be at the end of the main handler list

`DefaultServlet` needs to exist in your `ServletContextHandler`

You are missing a required `resourceBase` for your `ServletContextHandler` (this is a path or URL pointing to a valid location to make the `ServletContext` sane for finding resources)

A path spec of `*` is invalid. (remember, you can use prefix `/a/b/*`, suffix `*.foo`, exact `/a/b/c`, or default `/`)

So, to simplify ...

```java
package org.eclipse.jetty.demo;

import java.util.EnumSet;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncNCSARequestLog;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;

public class JerseyWithCors
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            new JerseyWithCors().exec();
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    public void exec() throws Exception
    {
        int port = 8080;
        Server server = new Server(port);
        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        server.setHandler(handlers);

        handlers.addHandler(getAccessLogHandler());
        handlers.addHandler(getMainServletContext());

        // DefaultHandler is always last for the main handler tree
        // It's responsible for Error handling of all prior handlers.
        // It will always respond (if the request reaches this far)
        handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }

    public Handler getAccessLogHandler()
    {
        RequestLogHandler logHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
        AsyncNCSARequestLog log = new AsyncNCSARequestLog();
        log.setFilename("logs/access-yyyy_mm_dd.log");
        logHandler.setRequestLog(log);
        return logHandler;
    }

    public Handler getMainServletContext()
    {
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        // always need a resource base
        context.setResourceBase("path/to/webroot");

        ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(ServletContainer.class,"/*");
        jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);
        jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES,"org.example.pss.resources");

        FilterHolder filterHolder = context.addFilter(CrossOriginFilter.class,"/*",EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
        filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM,"*");
        filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_HEADERS_PARAM,"Content-Type,Authorization,X-Requested-With,Content-Length,Accept,Origin");
        filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM,"GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.PREFLIGHT_MAX_AGE_PARAM,"5184000");
        filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOW_CREDENTIALS_PARAM,"true");

        // DefaultServlet is always last for a ServletContext
        context.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class,"/");

        return context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Joakim. An example like this would enhance the documentation for Jetty, embedded setup is not as well covered as webapp operation and static configuration files.

Comment: I still don't get the CORS header? I added:         filterHolder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.EXPOSED_HEADERS_PARAM,("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"));
and still don't get it. So no cross domain support do far. How do I get this?

I GET with header:

Host: pss.hcl.com:8088
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Get: